# Why is an array multiplied by [0] equal to the first element?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
print ([12,2][0])
```

The result is `12`

```
print ([12,2][1])
```

The result is `2`. Why?

**Question update**

I can't understand:

```
target_f = self.model.predict(state)
target_f[0][action] = target
```

https://github.com/keon/deep-q-learning/blob/master/dqn.py#L51

Why does `target_f` have an index `[0]` then another index `[action]`? What is this doing?

In my C programming experience, it should be a 2D array index. Is it the same here?

Comment: You're not doing any multiplication here. Your just making a list `[12,2]` and indexing it with `[0]` or `[1]`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I don't think this question is about slice notation, is it?

Comment: @Taegyung The question about slice notation is broader, simple indexing is also explained in the answers.

Comment: Because that’s how arrays and lists work. 0 is the first position, 1 is the second, and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `[12, 2]` is a list, and next notation: `[0]` or `[1]` is indexing.

You can test it if you try to print: `print([12, 2][2])` you should get index out of range error.

EDIT: to answer your second question:

It is hard to say. `target_f = self.model.predict(state)` - it is some kind of structure and I can't find information about this structure in the link you put above.

But we can consider some similar structure. Let's say you have:

```
target_f = [{'action': 'value1', 'action2': 'valuex'}, {'action': 'value2', 'another_key': 'another_value'}]
```

In your code `target_f[0][action] = target`:

`[0]` is index in list. It stands for fist element of list: `{'action': 'value1', 'action2': 'valuex'}`

`[action]` is key in the dictionary. It stands for `value1`.

Since you are typing: `target_f[0][action] = target` thats mean you want to update your `value1` by new value `target`. Your new stucture will looks like that:

```
target_f = [{'action': target, 'action2': 'valuex'}, {'action': 'value2', 'another_key': 'another_value'}]
```

Comment: can you also explain what does it mean in 'target_f[0][action] = target'?

Comment: It depends on the kind of structure, but I assume that target_f is a list of dictionaries. Hope explanation above will help you understand it ;)

Comment: Very helpful, thanks a lot.